# Option Buttons and text Boxes Not pulling info from worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button

I am creating a list for emergency staffing at a hospital.  The objective is to use a userform to minimize errors.  The add info userform works perfectly and adds the data to the worksheet.  But the Edit userform has a searchable combobox pulls the names but does not pull any of the other data into the userform.

I have written the code in several ways in order to pull the data but nothing has worked.  The combobox still populates but does not pull the data for any of the textboxes or option buttons.

```
Private Sub Full_Name_Change()
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Master")
LastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

    If Val(Me.Full_Name.Value) = ws.Cells(i, "C") Then
        Me.First_Name = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value
        Me.Last_Name = ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
        Me.MainPX = ws.Cells(i, "D").Value
        Me.AltPX = ws.Cells(i, "E").Value
        Me.Job_Role = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
        Me.WristBand = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
        Me.Team = ws.Cells(i, "H").Value
        Me.Shift_Hours = ws.Cells(i, "J").Value

        If ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "Surgical" Then
        Me.Surgical.Value = True
    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "Neuro" Then
        Me.Neuro.Value = True
    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "Cardiology" Then
        Me.Cardiology.Value = True
    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "Med-Tele" Then
        Me.Med_Tele.Value = True
    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "Renal" Then
        Me.Renal.Value = True
    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "Womens" Then
        Me.Womens.Value = True
    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "NICU" Then
        Me.NICU.Value = True
    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "L&D" Then
        Me.Lab_Del.Value = True
    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "ICU" Then
        Me.ICU.Value = True
    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "CVICU" Then
        Me.CVICU.Value = True
    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "Pediatrics" Then
        Me.Peds.Value = True
    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "ED" Then
        Me.ED.Value = True
    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "Children's ED" Then
        Me.Child_ED.Value = True
    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "TRED" Then
        Me.TRED.Value = True

End If

End If
Next i

End Sub
```

[Screen Shot of the Userform Worksheet Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLCVt.jpg)

Comment: Looking at the screenshot you have attached, I hope that the few phone numbers that look real are actually made up.  If not, I'd suggest removing the image and uploading a new one with sample data

Comment: @DBrown replace `If Val(Me.Full_Name.Value) = ws.Cells(i, "C") Then` by `If Val(Me.Full_Name.Value) = ws.Cells(i, "C").Value Then`

Comment: @Dorian...replace it with what?  I have looked at your suggestion but it looks the same...maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Dorian is suggesting you add `.Value` before the `Then`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad exactly didn't get the notification

Comment: Side note: instead of all those `If else` statements, look into [`Select Case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/select-case-statement)

Comment: @Dorian ...Sorry for my oversight.  I added the .Value but still the information is not pulling into the fields on the userform.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad..thank you for pointing that out to me...I totally missed that